# POSTGRESQL Insert Multiple Rows from given JSON array, use results from insert to do other inserts

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

**TL;DR**
Music Streaming app - allows users to upload their own files.
Files will be stored in a FileSet.
I want to pass in more than one FILE(array of fileRecords), with one FILESET, and insert into the appropriate tables.

Sorry if this is a little confusing - basically I am working with 3 tables:

**File table**

```
CREATE TABLE file
(
    -- Most tables should have a table_id & table_cuid
    file_id         BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL ,
    file_cuid       VARCHAR     NOT NULL,

    -- This section is specific to this table
    user_id         BIGINT      NOT NULL,

    -- File fields
    filename        VARCHAR     NOT NULL,
    last_modified   TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    size_in_bytes   VARCHAR     NOT NULL,
    mime_type       VARCHAR     NOT NULL,

    -- Most tables should also have timestamps
    created_timestamp  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE  NOT NULL,
    updated_timestamp  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE  NOT NULL,

    -- Constraints
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)   REFERENCES users (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT file_cuid_unique  UNIQUE     (file_cuid)
)
```

**FileSet Table**

```
CREATE TABLE fileset
(
    -- Most tables should have a table_id & table_cuid
    fileset_id         BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL ,
    fileset_cuid       VARCHAR     NOT NULL,

    user_id         BIGINT      NOT NULL,

    -- Fileset fields TBD

    created_timestamp  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE  NOT NULL,
    updated_timestamp  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE  NOT NULL,

    -- Constraints
    PRIMARY KEY (fileset_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)   REFERENCES users (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT cuid_unique_fileset  UNIQUE     (fileset_cuid)
)
```

and finally a **File_FileSet_Rel Table**

```
CREATE TABLE file_fileset_rel
(
    file_id         BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
    fileset_id      BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (file_id)  REFERENCES file   (file_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fileset_id)   REFERENCES fileset (fileset_id),
    UNIQUE      (file_id, fileset_id)
)
```

Every song will have one FileSet associated with it, and that fileset has one/multiple files associated.

The function below (file_upload_process) allows me to add the File to the table (returning **file_id**), as well as adding the Fileset to the table (returning **fileset_id**), and finally the function inserts both of these values into the final table **file_fileset_rel**

**file_upload_process.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_upload_process(
  _file_cuid VARCHAR,
  _fileset_cuid VARCHAR,
  _cognito_id VARCHAR,
  _name VARCHAR,
  _last_modified TIMESTAMP,
  _size DECIMAL,
  _type VARCHAR
)
RETURNS TABLE(
  fileId BIGINT,
  fileSetID BIGINT
)
AS $file_upload_process$
DECLARE
v_user_id BIGINT;
v_file_id BIGINT;
v_fileset_id BIGINT;
BEGIN

-- Create Song/ Update song
  -- store user_id
  v_user_id := (
    SELECT * FROM get_user_id(_cognito_id)
  );

  -- --Insert In FILE table
  v_file_id := (
    SELECT *
    FROM create_file(
    _file_cuid,
    v_user_id,
    _name,
    _last_modified,
    _size,
    _type
    )
  );

  --Insert into fileset table
  v_fileset_id := (
  SELECT * FROM create_fileset(_fileset_cuid, v_user_id)
  );

  RETURN QUERY
  INSERT INTO file_fileset_rel(file_id, fileset_id)
  VALUES (
    v_file_id,
    v_fileset_id
  )
  RETURNING file_fileset_rel.file_id,
            file_fileset_rel.fileset_id;
END;
$file_upload_process$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Which calls the following functions within:

**create_file.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_file(
  _file_cuid VARCHAR,
  _user_id BIGINT,
  _name VARCHAR,
  _last_modified TIMESTAMP,
  _size DECIMAL,
  _type VARCHAR
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  _file_id BIGINT
)
AS $create_file$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
-- Create Song/ Update song
  INSERT INTO file(
    file_cuid,
    user_id,
    filename,
    last_modified,
    size_in_bytes,
    mime_type,
    created_timestamp,
    updated_timestamp
  )
  VALUES(
    _file_cuid,
    _user_id,
    _name,
    _last_modified,
    _size,
    _type,
    now(),
    now()
  )
  RETURNING "file".file_id;
END;
$create_file$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And the create_fileset function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_fileset(
  _fileset_cuid VARCHAR,
  _user_id BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  _fileset_id BIGINT
)
AS $create_fileset$
BEGIN
-- Create Song/ Update song
  RETURN QUERY
  INSERT INTO fileset(
    fileset_cuid,
    user_id,
    created_timestamp,
    updated_timestamp
  )
  VALUES(
    _fileset_cuid,
    _user_id,
    now(),
    now()
  )
  RETURNING "fileset".fileset_id;
END;
$create_fileset$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The issue I'm having is that this function only allows you to add 1 file at a time, users could upload 5-10 files for 1 song (1 fileset) and so I need a way to loop through the array of fileRecords and store the values of those fields in the FILE table columns - finally allowing me to add multiple records to the file_fileset_rel table.

If anyone has easier ways to do all of this, or more importantly a solution to the MANY vs One insert would be a huge help.

EDIT:
Example of **CURRENT** body being sent to lambda - before passing to postgresql function
URL -> fileset/{filesetCuid}/file

```
body: {
"cognitoId" : "9dc766a0-c5c9-4455-932e-46c243c80266",
"fileRecord" : {
    "fileCuid" : "someotherfilecuid23",
    "name" : "file_name",
    "last_modified" : "06/03/1995",
    "size" : 530,
    "type" : "mp3/audio"
}
}
```

End goal - send multiple files:
URL -> fileset/{filesetCuid}/file

```
body: {
"cognitoId" : "9dc766a0-c5c9-4455-932e-46c243c80266",
"fileRecords" : [{
    "fileCuid" : "someotherfilecuid23",
    "name" : "file_name",
    "last_modified" : "06/03/1995",
    "size" : 530,
    "type" : "mp3/audio"
}, {...}, {...}]
}
```

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag? Do you need a solution for both DBMS products?

Comment: I figured it may not be a language-specific issue, or rather, that the solution in mysql would shed some light on how I might do it in postgresql

Comment: It would be helpful to see the structure of the json you are starting with.

Comment: Apologies - editted to reflect.

Comment: _Every song will have one FileSet associated with it, and that fileset has one/multiple files associated._

Not sure why you have this linking table in the first place since you apparently don't need a ManyToMany relation. Seems you could simply use a `file.fileset_id` that would be declared as `FOREIGN KEY (fileset_id) REFERENCES fileset (fileset_id)`. (And why not simply call the primary keys `id`, as usual?)

Comment: My poorly worded question probably caused a little confusion - Song A is created on the UI - User uploads FileA - FileA is added to FilesetA. If the user creates another Song on the UI - Song B, and this song also requires File A , the solution you suggested won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an elegant solution you can adapt from [this PostgREST issue](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1118#issuecomment-391379263). You could also use a [`LOOP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) in your `file_upload_process.sql` that wraps all your function calls.

The former is better because, it's a nice all-in-one upsert logic:

- it relies on the target table's definition (e.g. `DEFAULT` values are set on the fly)
- you can directly pass a JSON array (i.e. you *may* omit values that are not required)
- you can handle conflicts on your `UNIQUE` constraints (and retrieve the existing row's `id` automatically!)